# What is the right way - Bring wellness in life/brings wellness in life

Tags: verbs, verb-agreement

What is the right way to write/pronounce - Bring wellness in life/brings wellness in life, which one is correct word to be used in above sentence bring or brings

Answer (score 1):

The statement in question is not complete. It can either be bring or brings depending upon what precedes the word.
For example:
Her only goal was to bring wellness in life.
Your good deeds always bring wellness in life.
The above answer is based on pure assumption that the statement is not complete on its own. And not a command.
If command, it should simply be, Bring wellness in life. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a specific rule regarding this, but to answer your questions, it should be "Bring wellness to life" as is the case for all general statements. E.g. Bring joy to the world/ Treat others the way you wanted to be treated./ Love one another.

Just think of it as having the phrase "you should" at the start.

Comment: I have done a bit of research and the grammatical mood of your sentence is called imperative mood, which forms commands and requests. Imperative imply a second person subject, which is why you shouldn't add 's' after the verb :)